# Delphi RAD Studio Deployment Manager Remote Path for Appx Deployment

Tags: deployment, delphi-xe, desktop-bridge, appx

I'm searching for some documentation of the Delphi RAD Studio deployment manager, that describes in detail available remote path settings, if I like to include additional files, that have to be deployed to the HomePath (AppData Sub-Folders on Windows) or to HomePath for other platforms?
Are there any variables for special folders like homepath?

Is it possible to include additional files for AppData subfolders on Windows for an appx Windows Store deployment (for example some SQLite database to AppData\Roaming\examplefoldername\data\name.db or some config file to AppData\Roaming\examplefoldername\config.cfg)